# Duplicate classes after cocoapods update

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I am using ZXingObjC library installed via CocoaPods. Now I added Fabric and Crashlytics so my pod file looks like this:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'Project' do
pod 'ZXingObjC', '~> 3.0'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
end

target 'ProjectTests' do

end
```

I was using bridging header before but I updated CocoaPods to 0.38.2. I have problems with build the Project so I was searching for answers and I found that I don't need no longer bridging header with CocoaPods and I can just use:

```
import ZXingObjC
```

It still wasn't working so I just delete content of Pods folder and run `pod install` command and now it's working. I can build project. But I have still problem with duplicate classes. After launch of app I get many warnings like this:

```
Class ZXAI013103decoder is implemented in both
/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/06B79252-5593-4B8F-81F6-626C4886B2E7/Project.app/Frameworks/ZXingObjC.framework/ZXingObjC and 
/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/06B79252-5593-4B8F-81F6-626C4886B2E7/Project.app/Project. 
One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

Where could be the problem? The library looks its working correctly but still I want to solve these problems. Thanks for help

P.s.: I have iOS with Deployment Target 7.0 and I get these warnings when building project which could be related to my problem:

```
ld: warning: embedded dylibs/frameworks are only supported on iOS 8.0 and later (@rpath/ZXingObjC.framework/ZXingObjC)
ld: warning: embedded dylibs/frameworks are only supported on iOS 8.0 and later (@rpath/Pods_GexPay.framework/Pods_GexPay)
```

Comment: Well as the warnings said, you can't use external frameworks under iOS 7. If you want to support iOS 7 you should update you podfile. Remove the `use_frameworks!` line and replace the first line by `platform :ios, '7.0'`

Comment: As for the duplicate class, did you add some external frameworks manually (not using cocoa pods). If yes, which ones ?

Comment: Without `use_frameworks!` I can't get application to build. I have linker problems `ld: 1215 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64` and many `duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_...` I guess same problems as above but with `use_frameworks!` I can build app and without I cannot. And for second question I have added some libraries as source files (Locksmith, PKHUD, AEXML) but no external frameworks.

Comment: You should set your deployment target to iOS 8.0, your app will not work under iOS 7.As for the duplicate class implementation, it means what it means, it's implemented by ZXingObjC which you added with cocoa pods and reimplemented in your source code or in the source code that you added manually. Make a project wide search for ZXAI013103decoder.

Comment: I've tried search for classes from ZXingObjC and I got results just in Pods project in Pods folder. Nothing found in my main project (except usage ofcourse).